# Conditional cast from UITableViewCell to UITableViewCell always succeds

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, compiler-warnings

When I'm compiling my app, I get a warning and I don't know how to fix or hide it. Conditional cast from UITableViewCell to UITableViewCell always succeeds

This is my part of the code, where the warning appears.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayPDF.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellPDF", for: indexPath)
        as? UITableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    cell.textLabel?.text = arrayPDF[indexPath.row] + ".pdf"
    return cell
}
```

This part of my code generates the warning.

```
as? UITableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
```

Everything is working fine. I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically you are discouraged from using the syntax `guard ... else { return UITableViewCell() }`. If you need to cast the type to a custom type **force unwrap** it. The cast must not fail if everything is hooked up correctly. If it does it reveals a **design** mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellPDF", for: indexPath)` returns a `UITableViewCell` object.

So, when you do:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellPDF", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
```

You are casting an `UITableViewCell` object to an `UITableViewCell`. Xcode just tells you that is useless.

If your class is a `UITableViewCell`, you can just use:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellPDF", for: indexPath)
```

If it is a custom class, you can use the guard but replace the `as? UITableViewCell` part with `as? MyCustomTableViewCellClass`.

Regards,

IMACODE

Answer (score 0):

You used guard .. else{},So it must optional,I guess the function you need is the first not the last:
    open func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell? // Used by the delegate to acquire an already allocated cell, in lieu of allocating a new one.

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell // newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly,
```

You can right with eigther one in this way:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellPDF", for: indexPath)
```

OR

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellPDF") else { return UITableViewCell() }
```